# iPhone to make a sound when it shuts down due to low battery

Tags: iphone, audio, battery, notifications, shutdown

Is there a way to have the iPhone make a sound just before it goes to sleep due to low battery (i.e. when battery goes from `1%` to `0%`)?

Comment: Never came across any native way to do that.. well the thing is also that my iPhone is silent most of the times, even when it dies. Are you looking for apps to do that? ironically it will speed up battery death. And the app will most probably be made dormant by the OS, when it approaches 3 %

Comment: Actually, I think the old (ancient) iOSes were doing a sound in that case, we're looking at 10 years ago...

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no foolproof way of setting the iPhone to make a sound before it goes to sleep due to low battery.